# how to use app from github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I want to use [app](https://github.com/railscasts/episode-119) from github , i cloned it , 
but when i try `bundle install` , it requires a gem file .
I copied my gem file from other Local app ,  'bundle install ' is successfull , but when i try 'rake db:migrate' i see it:

```
    rusik@rusik-K50AF:~/work/ruby/episode-119/blog$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- initializer

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rusik@rusik-K50AF:~/work/ruby/episode-119/blog$ rake db:migrate --trace
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- initializer
/home/rusik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/rusik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/rusik/work/ruby/episode-119/blog/config/boot.rb:54:in `load_initializer'
/home/rusik/work/ruby/episode-119/blog/config/boot.rb:38:in `run'
/home/rusik/work/ruby/episode-119/blog/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
/home/rusik/work/ruby/episode-119/blog/config/boot.rb:109:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rusik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/rusik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/rusik/work/ruby/episode-119/blog/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rusik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/rusik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/    home/rusik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/rusik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/rusik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/rusik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/home/rusik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/home/rusik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/rusik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/rusik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rusik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/rusik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

, 
I tried to copy my db test.sqlite3 from my LOCAL app, but it doesn't work, the same problem.

So ,of'course, i tried `rails server`, but it doesn't work.

So , how to setup app from github?

Answer (score 0):

It's rails 2 app, so there is no bundler at all. If you want to run it you should read README:

> To setup the app, just run `rake setup`.

Comment: so , 1 ) i must to copy gemfile ? 2 ) i try rake setup , but it is not work, the same errors in trace

Comment: 1. no, you should not. 2. I think you are using rails 3 instead of rails 2.